# How to get the id of dynamically created anchor text that uses event delegation, vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', getRecipe)
document.querySelector('#recipeContainer').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.className === 'recipeTitles') {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
});

function getRecipe() {
  let data = [{
    id: 661447,
    title: "Square Deviled Eggs",
    image: "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661447-312x231.jpg",
    imageType: "jpg",
    usedIngredientCount: 2
  }, {
    id: 638035,
    title: "Chicken Cordon Bleu",
    image: "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/638035-312x231.jpg",
    imageType: "jpg",
    usedIngredientCount: 2
  }];

  let recipeTitles = function() {
    return data.map((el, i) => `<h2><a href="#" class="recipeTitles" id="${el.id}">${el.title}</a></h2>`).join('')
  };

  document.querySelector('#recipeContainer').innerHTML = recipeTitles();
}

function showRecipe(id, data) {
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data.title)
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Seach!</button>
<div id="recipeContainer"></div>
```

My question is how do I access the anchor text id in the event listener? because I would like to use it in the showRecipe() function.

In the actual program it will run like this

1. getRecipe() calls an api that returns an array of objects which are recipes and a lot of other relevant information.
2. getRecipe then takes the recipe titles, wraps them in <h2> and <a> tags and adds the recipe id as the <a> id and inputs that into the innerHTML
3. I click one of the anchor tags which triggers an event listener through event delegation and I would like to run functions on it using it's id.

I have seen other people ask what seem to be similar questions, but none using vanilla javascript. All seem to use JQuery or something like that, and I'm afraid I don't know that at all.

Comment: Your code already works, you just need to change `this.id` to `event.target.id`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(event) { let id = event.target.id; console.log(id); }) )`

Comment: What @RoryMcCrossan said, or use a `function()` instead of a `=>` for the event handler so that `this` remains unbound until the handler is called.

Comment: easiest option is add onclick event also in your map in recipeTitles function; - return data.map((el, i) => `<h2><a href="#" class="recipeTitles" onclick="showRecipe('${el.id}', '${el.title}')" id="${el.id}">${el.title}</a></h2>`).join('')

Comment: @Immanuel I had that before actually, but was told not to use inline JS